# Ruby on Rails under Apache in a shared hosting environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache

I'm helping a friend out by writing a little website for his research project. One of the platforms I'm considering writing it on is Ruby on Rails. However, the University servers he's got to use don't have Ruby installed.

I understand that I can install Ruby in user-space, and I presume this means I can install Rails. But the first port of call for web requests to the server will be Apache 2.x, and I don't have the ability to install new modules. Will I be able to hand off to requests to Rails? Is mod_proxy with Mongrel a valid solution, or is there a better way? What if they won't allow mod_proxy?